# How to convert a mesh or shape into an Octomap?

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to convert 3D meshes into Octomaps, to obtain the swept volume of a robot trajectory.

The only conversion I found is [binvox2bt](https://octomap.github.io/octomap/doc/binvox2bt_8cpp.html), but this loads a mesh file directly into an octree, and does not allow transformation before conversion.

[This issue](https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/gpu-voxels/issues/29) seems to imply that there are no easy solutions. Does anyone have a good project or method to point to?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381780/how-to-convert-a-mesh-or-shape-into-an-octomap?/) by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2180 on 2021-07-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2021-07-06**:
What is your mesh format ? , if its a format that Gazebo supports, you my spawn the mesh to a Gazebo world.
I have a gazebo plugin that can acquire octomap(optionally a pointcloud) of world. Though its only in ROS2; https://github.com/NMBURobotics/vox_nav/tree/foxy/vox_nav_utilities, if you are interested I can provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I looked through the code of [gpu-voxels](https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/gpu-voxels). It looks like they [made some functions to convert URDF shapes to point clouds](https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/gpu-voxels/blob/master/packages/gpu_voxels/src/gpu_voxels/robot/urdf_robot/robot_link.cpp#L191). The point clouds are then transformed and converted to octrees in their final positions.

The mesh format has to be `.binvox`, but the `binvox2bt` tool linked in the OP should be able to convert.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0